# TensorFlowJS fails to load a JS generated image

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

TensorFlowJS can load the image from HTML but cannot normally load an image from a JavaScript generated image object.

The code is shown as follows. The first group of loading methods can load the image from HTML.

```
h = document.getElementById("dandelion");
let image1 = await tf.browser.fromPixels(h);
var x1 = document.createElement("CANVAS");
tf.browser.toPixels(image1, x1);
document.body.append(x1);
```

The second group of loading methods will generate a `online_img` with a link to an online image. But when I try to draw the loaded image, I only got a black square.

```
let online_img = await document.createElement("IMG"); 
online_img.setAttribute("id", "loaded_image")
online_img.setAttribute("src", str);
online_img.setAttribute("width", "200");
online_img.setAttribute("height", "100");
await document.body.appendChild(online_img);
let image = await tf.browser.fromPixels(online_img);
var x = document.createElement("CANVAS");
tf.browser.toPixels(image, x);
document.body.append(x);
```

So I wonder if there is any way to successfully load the images **with second group of methods**.

Thanks!!

The full HTML code is presented here.

```
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs"> </script>
<head></head>
<body>
 <img id="dandelion" crossorigin height="320" width="480" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/719fF478nPL._SX425_.jpg"></img>
</body>
<script>
async function getImage_online(str){
  // load and draw from html: success. 
//   const image1 = tf.browser.fromPixels(dandelion);
  h = document.getElementById("dandelion");
  let image1 = await tf.browser.fromPixels(h);
  var x1 = document.createElement("CANVAS");
  tf.browser.toPixels(image1, x1);
  document.body.append(x1);

  // load the image from generated image: loaded image is black. 
  let online_img = await document.createElement("IMG"); 
  online_img.setAttribute("id", "loaded_image")
  online_img.setAttribute("src", str);
  online_img.setAttribute("width", "200");
  online_img.setAttribute("height", "100");
  await document.body.appendChild(online_img);
  let image = await tf.browser.fromPixels(online_img);
  var x = document.createElement("CANVAS");
  tf.browser.toPixels(image, x);
  document.body.append(x);

}

async function newRun_online(){
  let c = await getImage_online("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/719fF478nPL._SX425_.jpg"); // c: rose
}

newRun_online(); 

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing to load the image, because the image has not completed to load before.

```
image.onload = () => {
  tf.browser.toPixels(image, x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying the `onload` now. I'm new to JS.

Comment: I modified the code and it seems to work.```document.body.appendChild(online_img).onload = function(){
    let image = tf.browser.fromPixels(online_img);
    var x = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    tf.browser.toPixels(image, x);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  };```